# iPhone 5s, can't decline call

Tags: ios, iphone

Since last year, I have been using and iPhone 5s with iOS7 version.

My Problems are:

1. I haven't been able to decline an incoming call for some time.
2. There are two User interfaces available for incoming call. One interface has the option to Decline with red button. In the other interface, I can't find the option to decline.

Comment: Why are you not able to decline an incoming call? Do you not see the red "decline" button or does it not respond when pressed/tapped? Does it happen irregardless of sleep/logged in state of the phone or only for calls arriving while the phone is at sleep/turned off?

Comment: It's probably when the phone is not in the sleep/turned off state. The incoming call interface does not give you the "decline" option.